# Microsoft Azure: Unable to add the new virtual machine to the existing virtual network

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have an existing virtual network in my subscription. Three virtual machines are already assigned to that virtual network since last 2-3 months. But something has got changed in the portal. I am trying to create another virtual machine in the same existing virtual network through the new portal. But I am not getting the available virtual network in my subscription & region while trying to choose the virtual network for the new virtual machine. Unable to add the new virtual machine to the existing virtual network though both are in same subscription & region.

Comment: please add any code/ script and error response for folks to provide better solutions.

Comment: Have you check the resource group is same or difference? because i have seen update as classics resource have been assign default resourece group.